# Java - How to get coordinates of Vertex in a TreeLayout in JUNG?

Tags: layout, coordinates, vertex, jung

Is there a way to get coordinates of a Vertex in JUNG using a TreeLayout, as there is no methods like getX and getY in Abstract Layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are such methods in AbstractLayout: 
http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/layout/AbstractLayout.html#getX(V)